# Apache doesn't recognize .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ubuntu-12.04

I'm a little bit confused; my Apache2 doesn't read any of my .htaccess.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and the last line of my `etc/apache2/apache2.conf` looks like that:

```
<Directory />
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
AllowOverride All
Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

I also successfully restarted my Apache after I added `AllowOverride All` and `Options FollowSymLinks` to these lines. 
I put now also just some rubbish like `some rubbish` in my .htaccess in the root dir `/var/www/` but I even doesn't get a 500 error. Confusing. Anyone who could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the configuration of the Apache default virtualhost, placed inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and not only in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, that it is used only for general webserver configuration.